# How do I set grid spacing in gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I have yaxis from 0 to 100. I want a grid line after every 10 units. How can I do that? That is, how can I draw grid lines after each 10 units?

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at "help grid", you probably want to do something like

```
set yrange [0:100]
set xrange [0:10]

set grid ytics mytics  # draw lines for each ytics and mytics
set mytics 2           # set the spacing for the mytics
set grid               # enable the grid

plot sin(x)*100
```

Comment: I remember that there exists one parameter to make those grids more regular. However, I could not find such description in `help`. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by more regular? by default they are at the tics level, which normally are equally spaced... You might want to adjust your [xy]ranges to get the top and bottom grid line nicely spaced to the axis, but otherwise I don't know what you mean...

Comment: I think I mean here `grid minor;`.

Comment: as in the example I gave, you can set the m[x|y|...]tics to get subspacing. See the example I gave where you have a yaxis from 0-100 with a grid spacing of every 10.

Comment: @Arun how would I make gnuplot on every 2nd minor tics? so for example the x axis has 0 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00  I would like maj grid lines on 0 and 1.00 and dotted grid lines on 0.5, where 0.25 and .75 have nothing?

Comment: I don't think gnuplot can do that, but I might be wrong. I think you only have xtics and mxtics and you either have grid lines everywhere on those or not.

One way to cheat could be to set x2tics and mx2tics, hide the labels by setting them to an empty string and then use different mx2tics spacing and plot a subgrid on mx2tics. Haven't tried this out, but this should work. You would see different mtics on the top of your plot than on the bottom though.

Answer (score 3):

The `ytics` variable controls how often or sparse the `y` scale values will be printed and thus the grid lines will be drawn.

```
set ytics 10  # y scale marks and values will be at every 10th unit
set grid      # grid turned on at each scale values
replot        # replot your graph
```

The `mytics` controls the minor marks on the `y` scale. The `set grid mytics` makes the `y` scale minor grid lines visible.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality because it was predominately code.  Try explaining your answer in a little more depth.