# How to use power of 10 in GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to force the use of power of 10 on my chart but the best I got so far was this

[image]

using `set format y '%.1tx10^{%T}'`, while what I want is something like: 0, 1x10¹, 1.5x10², and so on.. in the y axis.

I already read the [Format specifiers](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html) doc but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: With version 5.0, the format you want is the default, `%h`. And the link you give is for gnuplot 4.2, which is ancient.

Comment: In fact, I'm using v5.0 patch level 3. The default option does not work well for me because I want to have all the numbers in the power of 10 and it looks like gnuplot does not use this if the numbers are below a threshold, I get 100 Instead of 10², for example.

Comment: @DavidsonDFGL you might want to specify the precision explicitly, i.e., `set format y '%.2h'`

Comment: check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069093/how-do-i-set-grid-spacing-in-gnuplot
might help.

Comment: thanks @user10574105, but the ewcz's answer already solve my problem, since it was a comment, I couldn't mark as solved, sorry.